# Why there is no Calendar sync Option on android 4.2.2? (Lenovo A850)

Tags: sync, calendar

I can't find the sync option for calendar in my new Android 4.2.2 phone.
There is every other option such as: Gmail, Google+, Contacts and so on but no calendar!
Can somebody help me to make it work?
By the way, I have rooted my phone. Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed Google Calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Install [Calendar app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar)

Enable calendar sync

[image]

Select calendars to sync

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that running "Google Calendar" app (download from Google Play) on my Huawei synced the "hidden" google calendar (look into the apps settings and calendars on the top left hand corner). Running this app forced a calendar sync and all my events are now visible and the Calendar Sync option in the Gmail account in the Users & Accounts section of Settings is now visible again.

I hope someone out there finds this helpful.